# Does the placement of “tout” change the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

"Nous disons tout" means "We tell all" but "Nous tout disons" means "We all tell" right? If this is true does that mean I can say "Nous tout allons te dire tout" as "We are all going to tell you all" right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tout" is a global adjective, literally meaning "all" or "every*thing*"

If you want to say "all of **us**/all of **them**" then you need to use "tous."

So, instead of "Nous tout disons..." you should use,

> "Nous disons **tous**..."

Notice the verb *usually* goes before the "tous."

That being said, you could say,

> "Nous allons **tous** te dire **tout**"

Comment: But how about sentences like 'Nous finis tous' which I think means 'We finish everything' and a sentence like 'Nous tous finis' which means we all finish. Does the placement matter?

Comment: Or is it the word?

Comment: @MarcoRubenAbuyuanLlanes "Nous finissons tous" means, "We all finish" and "Nous finissons tout" means "We finish everything." This is easier to hear because the "s" at the end of "tous" is always pronounced, but "tout" is always pronounced [too]. Both. You would not say, "Je tout vois," or "Nous tout *finissons*."  It would be, "Je vois tout" and "Nous finissons tous tout." Does that make sense?

Comment: note that it could also be "nous allons tous tout te dire"

Answer (score 0):

*Tout* étant un COD, sa position **ne change pas le sens**. A ne pas confondre avec *tous* (rattaché au sujet *nous*).

Il vaut mieux coller *tous* à *nous*, si on veut renforcer *nous*, mais on peut le mettre après le verbe.

En général, on met *tout* avant l'infinitif (après est aussi possible).

> Nous tous allons tout te dire.
>
> Nous allons tous tout te dire.
>
> Nous tous allons te dire tout.
>
> Nous allons tous te dire tout.